# Xcode 8.3.2 doesn't work with Alamofire 4.4.0

Tags: xcode, xcode8, alamofire

Running my project, which uses Swift3, with Xcode 8.3.2. I face this issue:

> Alamofire Issue - “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

My project depends on Alamofire 4.4.0

When I fix the "Swift Language version" in "Build Settings" to the Swift3, and try to run again the Alamofire module starts throwing "Swift compiler errors" (Use of undeclared type 'HTTPHeaders', Use of undeclared type 'DataRequest' and so on) - It cannot find a lot of modules.

Did anyone faced this issue already? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You might be better off checking the github page and raising an issue there if nobody else has come across it.: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues

Comment: Did you re-run `pod install` ?

Comment: I didn't find out that issue on Github. Yes, I did re run pod install.

Comment: You can always create your own issue there.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with cocoapods. It turned out that cocoapods didn't load the libraries files. I solved this issue by:

1. Updated cocoapods like described here https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692
2. Restarted Xcode
3. Ran "pod install"
4. Set the "Swift Language version" in "Build Settings" to the Swift3 for all pods.
5. Ran the app again.